# System.EntryPointNotFoundException when calling Task.Run() in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, task

This is baffling me. When clicking the button in the windows form project, the code below results in 'Exception thrown: 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll'. I cannot figure out why. The app doesn't crash, and the task (or any amount of tasks) continues just fine, with everything working as it should.

What's going on here?

```
namespace FormsExperiment
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
           InitializeComponent();            
        }        

        private void btn_fire_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(() => "Hello");            
        }        
    }
}
```

Edit: Trying this on another computer, I'm not able to reproduce the bug. I'm going to chalk this up to VS2015 weirdness that seems beyond the scope of stackoverflow. Thanks for the replies all - the code here works, the error just makes no sense.

Comment: The example code works for me. Is it everything you have in your application?

Comment: Just that and the other partial file which makes up the actual form, which I haven't touched.


Edit: Recreated with a fresh project, just added the button, the click function and the above code. Same error. I'm using VS2015, updated to the latest version today, but was getting this beforehand too.

Comment: Do you still need help with this ? have you posted on MSDN and also look at other answers here in S.O. regarding this issue ?

Comment: I do. This was my first stop after googling for answers for a few days, including looking on SO - I haven't seen this issue mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, the code you posted would work just fine. `EntryPointNotFoundException` means the CLR tried to load an assembly but couldn't find the entry point; not something one would expect from a process that has already started. Are you sure the code you posted is really a good representation of the code you're actually executing? Your description of _"task continues fine"_ is incongruous with the given example (which has nothing to "continue").

Comment: That's not a mere example - that is literally the entirety of the code. When I say the task continues fine, I just mean to stress that the EntryPointNotFoundException shows up in the console, but nothing crashes. And if I click the button again, that error doesn't pop up.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: Also, I'd be reinstalling the .NET framework if I something like this happened to me

Comment: I'll likely be doing that tomorrow. And, unfortunately, I don't know how to get more information than that. This is a Windows Form app with the Console output being redirected.